# Assign multiple taxids to a sequence when constructing a local BLAST database

Tags: blast, taxonomy, makeblastdb

I recently had a script fail due to poor handling of BLAST output. The BLAST `-outfmt staxids` field usually returns a single taxid, but occasionally it returns two or more taxids separated by a semicolon, such as `556514;701533`. Fixing the script to handle this should be fairly straightforward. But the original failure happened when I was searching a local copy of the NCBI nt database, and I'd like to create a test case with a small query and small database that reproduces this issue more rapidly.

I am familiar with the `-taxid` and `-taxid_map` flags of the `makeblastdb` command, but I have been unable to reproduce this behavior with BLAST; that is, make BLAST return multiple taxids for a sequence.

- If I provide `556514;701533` or `556514,701533` as a sequence's taxid with `-taxid` or `-taxid_map`, the `makeblastdb` command fails citing an integer conversion error.
- If I provide `556514 701533` as the taxid in the `taxid_map` file, the database will be indexed successfully but BLAST will return the invalid value `0` for `staxids`.
- If I duplicate each entry in the `-taxid_map` file so that there is an entry for each taxid (see below), only a single taxid is reported by BLAST.

  ```
  seq1 556514
  seq1 701533
  seq2 556514
  seq2 701533
  seq3 556514
  seq3 701533
  ...
  ```

When constructing a custom local BLAST database, how do I associated a database sequence with more than one taxid?

---

**UPDATE**: The offending entry (or one such entry) appears to be a duplicate or merged entry in the nt database. When I use `blastdbcmd` to retrieve the subject sequence by accession, nt returns a sequence with two deflines on single line, like so.

```
>accession1 plain text description >accession2 other description
ACGT...
```

Using either of the two accessions, `blastdbcmd` will return the exact same entry, and the two staxids shown above correspond to the two distinct accessions.

**So part of the issue seems to be how to construct a BLAST database such that multiple accessions can point to a single entry/subject.**

Comment: Can't you just jiggle it around in pandas? That was my approach leveraging local blast, albeit for something it was probably not intended to do

Comment: @M__ I already have what I think is a solution, yes involving post-processing the BLAST tabular results in a dataframe. But I'll re-emphasize that I'm trying to construct a test case that will reproduce this behavior *in BLAST*.

Comment: Thanks now I understand. If a Blast expert answers I'll be enlightened too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I inquired with the NCBI BLAST help desk today, and within an hour they provided a very helpful response.

To summarize, when redundant records in the database are collapsed, the deflines (accessions + descriptions) of the original entries are placed on a single line separated by an invisible control character (Ctrl-A or `\x01`). The `makeblastdb` program will recognize this and associate multiple accessions (from the combined defline) and taxids (from the taxid_map file) to a single entry. If you are retrieving entries from e.g. nt or nr with `blastdbcmd`, you can use the `-ctrl_a` flag to format the data with these invisible control characters—by default the `>` character is used.

---

**tl;dr** I can reproduce the behavior described in the original question by:

1. creating a FASTA file containing an entry with multiple accessions separated by the invisible `\x01` character
2. create a taxid_map file mapping the accessions to different taxids
3. format the FASTA file with `makeblastdb -taxid_map ...`
4. perform a BLAST search with a query that matches the entry in question; `-outfmt "6 staxids"` will return a string with multiple taxids.

Comment: Thanks for answering your question. Its good to know the NCBI helpdesk is fast and knowledgeable.